# Is possible to programmatically control Network state in Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I checked [`DeviceNetworkInformation` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.devicenetworkinformation%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) and there are properties that return current state of network as `TRUE` or `FALSE`:

- [`IsCellularDataEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.devicenetworkinformation.iscellulardataenabled%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)
- [`IsWiFiEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.devicenetworkinformation.iswifienabled%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

I was wondering if there are APIs that allow to manipulate/set network state, lets say turn wireless ON/OFF or turn data connection ON/Off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly change the settings, but you can launch the [ConnectionSettingsTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394011%28v=vs.92%29), which will open up the relevant OS settings page.

Comment: Any hacks/workarounds so we can automatically turn wifi on/off?

Comment: Any workaround wouldn't get certified for inclusion in the Windows Marketplace.

Comment: I want it for my own phone, possible?